# displaying accurate results

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I'm creating a web site directory for my mobile site ([FOUND HERE](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2))

I have figured out how to display listings from my mysql table to my home page from my tables promo_cat list.

The thing im having trouble with is this:

once clicking on one of the catagories it leads me to my list.php page.

How do I get this page to display results related to the category clicked and not others?

For example:when clicking on "FREE" brings up this page: http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/list.php?id=FREE. Which displays all results. it should only display results that have a promo_cat field as "FREE" and should not display any other results as it does currently.

**My list.php code:**

```
<?php

include_once('include/connection.php');
include_once('include/article.php');

$article = new article;
$articles = $article->fetch_all();

?>

<html>

<head>
<title>xclo mobi</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="other.css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php include_once('header.html'); ?>


<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo">Category = ???</a>

<ol>
    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

<div class="border">
<a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?>" style="text-decoration: none">
<img src="<?php echo $article['promo_image']; ?>" border="0" class="img" align="left"><br />


<a href="<?php echo $data['promo_link']; ?>" target="_blank"><img alt="" title="" src="GO.png" height="50" width="50" align="right" /></a>

          <font class="title"><em><center><?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?></center></em></font>

<br /><br />

<font class="content"><em><center><?php echo $article['promo_content']; ?></center></em></font>

</div><br/><br />

          </a>

 <?php } ?>
</ol>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**/include/article.php**

```
<?php

class article {
public function fetch_all(){
    global $pdo;
      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mobi");
      $query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
              }

public function fetch_data($promo_title) {
   global $pdo;

 $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mobi WHERE promo_title = ?");
  $query->bindValue(1, $promo_title);
   $query->execute();

return $query->fetch(); 

}

}

?>
```

Comment: Your example makes it sound like you don't have a problem? You say you want it to display related results, don't you want it to only display results which are "FREE", which according to your example is what it's doing?

Comment: pleae re read my origional post. I have edited it. thanks.

Comment: `display listings from my mysql table` - Please edit your question and include your SQL statement then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, try this:

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { 
   if ($article['promo_cat'] === 'FREE') { ?>

   // Keep the rest of the code

   //instead of <?php } ?> - put...
   <?php } } ?>
```

Keep in mind, this is messy. But the `foreach` statement (I imagine) is being used to print out all posts. So, before printing out a post, you just check to see if the promo_title is FREE, GIFT, etc. If it's not, then it doesn't print that item.

You can make this more dynamic by passing in a $_GET variable (which you apparently are doing, but the code is never using this variable) with the current promo title and altering the conditional line to say

`if ($article['promo_cat'] === $_GET['id'])`

Hope that helps!

Comment: its not doing that for the GIFT case though.

Comment: Ah, I was clicking on the "Free" link on the top of the page, not the bottom. My mistake! +1 @Maximus2012 for being first anyhow!

Comment: yeah I was also doing that initially.

Comment: I've edited my answer now that you've provided more information.

Comment: hi Phas1c. my promo_title is the name of the offer for example GIFFGAFF, O2. mY LIST OF CATAGORIES IS SAVED AS promo_cat. thanks.

Comment: this code worked fantastic if ($article['promo_cat'] === $_GET['id']) { ?> thank you so much.

Comment: if you feel fit. please one up me so that I can do the same for you and others  as and when I get 15 rep.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make changes to the code for list.php based on the input it gets through GET parameter. something like:

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 'FREE'){
    // do something like display FREE items
}
elseif($_GET['id'] == 'GIFT') {
    // display GIFT items
}
else {
    // perform some default action 
}
```

This is to make it even more database driven (helpful when there are many categories):

```
$sql = "select * from categories where id = '".$_GET['id']."'";
if (mysql_results($sql)){
    // do something
}
else {
    // show error
}
```

Note that this is for demo only and in your code you should use PDO/MySQLI and prepared statements and not mysql_results function.

In light of more information provided by OP:
Change this

```
$articles = $article->fetch_all();
```

to

```
$articles = $article->fetch_data($_GET['id']);
```

in list.php and see if you get correct results.

Comment: will I need to do this for all of the catagories that I have?

Comment: yes. Or you can make this part database driven. See my edit above.

Comment: you can use a case statement, which may be better than lots of if statements. php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php‎

Comment: as I will be getting lots of offers that will come and go. I will have catagories that will only be available for a short while and not for a long time. I do not really want to have a hafe a code that is going to be pointless for a long time. basically when you hit FREE (at the bottom of my page) it shows this link: http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/list.php?id=FREE so it is already doing it! i just need it to display the relevent romotions.

Comment: exactly so its the list.php file that you need to change. Its always good to hard code the categories or use switch/case if there are only a few of them. Go with the database option if there a lot of categories.

Comment: thank you for this. my trouble is. what do I add to // do something?

Comment: will it help if I pasted my current list.php code so you can re arange it to fit?

Comment: i have added my list.php code. please can you see how I can rearange this to get the results Im looking for? thanks.

Comment: you need to do content filtering at the start of the code. What does code for 'include/article.php' look like ?

Comment: added this to my origional post.

Comment: adding this ---> if ($article['promo_cat'] === $_GET['id']) { ?> <--- after my foreach in list.php did the job. as Phas1c pointed out. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: if you feel fit. please one up me so that I can do the same for you and others  as and when I get 15 rep.