# displaying results and hiding duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I have a list of catagores found at the **bottom** of **[THIS PAGE](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/)**

this code:

```
<?php

include_once('include/article.php');


$article = new article;
$articles = $article->fetch_all();

?>



    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

 <div id="content">        
<a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>">
<li class="button"><ul class="pageitem">
<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>
</li></ul></div>
          </a>

 <?php } ?>
```

displays the value of the promo_cat field in my mysql table as a list:

as you can see. there are 2 "FREE" fields. How do I edit this code so that it does not show up any duplicates?

I understand that I need to use a DISTINCT feature but im not sure how to. Please help.

thank you.

**If you require any more coe from another page then please ask and I will edit this post and add it.**

Comment: this is related to another question that you posted. You need to do filtering in the fetch_all() function in article.php file.

Comment: show us the fetch_all in article

Comment: @Orangepill look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751536/displaying-accurate-results

Comment: hi Maximus2012. sorry for posting another topic so soon. yes this is semi related. the last one was about the list.php page not displaying. this is about the initial list on the index.php page. was going to ask this on that post but it would have got very confusing.

Comment: create a get_categories method on article class that performs the distint category query and returns the results.

Comment: simon's code below provides a good template for that... just change table to mobi

Comment: @Orangepill already changed it for him. Remember (php NoOB ఠ_ఠ) me?

Comment: @Simon_eQ had an identity crisis? and a location update?

Comment: I guess you can call it that. I may need an orange pill now. Btw: As a PHP guru, why don't you come to the [PHP room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) and chat with us. Its really nice there. @Orangepill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `promo_cat` FROM mobi WHERE `something`  = 'something'
```

More on [**DISTINCT**](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?97,53798,53798) from http://forums.mysql.com/

Comment: please one up my 2nd post so that I can do the same for others once it hit 15 rep. i found your code very useful. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

for future reference.

***changing my above code to:***

```
<?php

include_once('include/article.php');


$category = new category;
$articles = $category->fetch_all();

?>



    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

 <div id="content">        
<a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>">
<li class="button"><ul class="pageitem">
<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>
</li></ul></div>
          </a>

 <?php } ?>
```

***and adding a new CLASS to my /include/article.php that reads:***

```
class category {
public function fetch_all(){
    global $pdo;
      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `promo_cat` FROM mobi");
      $query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
              }

public function fetch_data($promo_cat) {
   global $pdo;

 $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mobi WHERE `something`  = 'something'");
  $query->bindValue(1, $promo_cat);
   $query->execute();

return $query->fetch(); 

}

}
```

***Fixed my problem.***

thank you.